# Python3 - Execute code only on class through decorator- inheritance

Tags: python-decorators

I am trying to execute a code only in one condition: when the code is executed inside the class A which inherit from class AI.

The output I wish I could have is the following:

```
 In [1]: import maintenance 
 In [2]: a = maintenance.A() 
 In [3]: a() 
 Out[3]: Stopping A 
         Executing the common task 
         Cleaning logs 
 In [4]: b = maintenance.B() 
 In [5]: b() 
 Out[5]: Stopping B 
         Executing the common task
```

The Code is the following:

```
 # module maintenance 

 1     from functools import wraps 
 2
```

The code to be executed by A is :

```
 3     def cleaning_logs(): 
 4         print("Cleaning logs") 
 5
```

In order not to touch the class A, I have created a decorator:

```
 6     def archive_log(func): 
 7         @wraps(func) 
 8         def enhanced_func(*args, **kwargs): 
 9             func(*args,**kwargs) 
10             cleaning_logs() 
11         return enhanced_func 
12
```

Because I think it is not possible to retrieve the information of the class from the above decorator, I have attempted to create a class decorator.  The below code is incomplete because here is my problem:

```
 13     def cls_archive_log(cls): 
 14         #... Missing Code : I have tried many things 
 15         #... Missing Code : I have tried many things 
 16         setattr(cls, '__call__', archive_log) 
 17         return cls 
 18
```

This class decorator that I am using in the following code:

```
 19     @cls_archive_log 
 20     class AI(object): 
 21         def __call__(self): 
 22             self.stop() 
 23             print("Executing the common task") 
 24 
 25     class A(AI): 
 26         def stop(self): 
 27             print('Stopping A') 
 28 
 29     class B(AI): 
 30         def stop(self): 
 31             print('Stopping B') 
 32
```

But really, I have tried everything I could for the class decorator.

Any idea how I could solve my problem through a decorator, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Every easy.  Just set the attribute as below:

```
16 def maintenance(cls):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
17     setattr(cls, '__call__', archive_logs(cls.__call__))                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
18     return cls
```

And decorate the class that need to implement the maintenance

```
31 @maintenance                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
32 class A(AI):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
33     def stop(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
34         print("Stopping A")
```

The full code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
from functools import wraps                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

def cleaning_logs():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    print("Cleaning logs")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

def archive_logs(func):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    @wraps(func)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    def enhanced_func(*args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        cleaning_logs()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    return enhanced_func                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

def maintenance(cls):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    setattr(cls, '__call__', archive_logs(cls.__call__))                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    return cls                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

class AI(object):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    @abstractmethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    def stop():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        raise NotImplemtedError('NotImplemtedError')                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    def __call__(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        self.stop()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        print("Executing the common AI task")                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

@maintenance                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
class A(AI):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    def stop(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        print("Stopping A")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

class B(AI):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    def stop(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        print("Stopping B")
```